# Write a program using bitwise operators to determine positive remaindar

Tags: c++

> Write a program that reads an integer value from the keyboard into a variable of type int, and uses one of the bitwise operators (i.e. not the % operator!) to determine the positive remainder when divided by 8.
>
> For example, 29 = (3x8)+5 and 14 = ( 2x8)+2 have positive remainder 5 and 2, respectively, when divided by 8.

I tried to search how can I solve it. What I did is to break given examples numbers into binary.

```
29 => 101001
8  => 001000
5 =>  000101
```

I don't know what is operation I should do with 29 and 8 to get result 5 in binary.

While searching there's some guys said that we should do (& operation with 7 )

```
remainder = remainder & 7 ;
```

Then I tried to do this with Value itself

```
value = value & 7 ;
```

and Here's my code After doing it ...

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
  int value = 0;
  int divisor = 8;
  int remainder = 0;

  cout << "Enter an integr and I'll divide it by 8 and give you the remainder!"
       <<endl;
  cin >> value;

  value = value & 7;
  remainder = value & divisor;
  cout << remainder;

  return 0;
}
```

It gave me result 0 when I use value 29. I don't know what I wrote was right or not.

Comment: 29 is not 101001 in binary. And why are you &ing with divisor? The remainder is just value & 7.

Comment: You don't seem to be actually using anything from C++/CLI (C++ modified to also support .Net), why did you tag tis question with it?

Comment: sorry I didn't get attention to this point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 8 is exactly `2^3`, the modulo-8 remainder of any number is composed of its last three binary digits, i. e. it equals the number bitwise-and 7:

```
unsigned rem8 = number & 7;
```

(7 is `111` in binary, that's why.)

Answer (score 3):

Simply `&` the number itself with 7. Also, `29 = 0b11101`. To generalise, the remainder when divided by a number `2 ^ n` is found by `&`ing it with `(2 ^ n) - 1` (`^` == power of)

Thus, to obtain remainder `modulo 16`, `&` with 15, and so on.

Comment: I got it .. but I didn't understand how could u know this point
"the remainder when divided by a number 2 ^ n is found by &ing it with (2 ^ n) - 1"